# Dependency Injection in Unit Tests, best practise

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm somewhat new to DI, and have a question regarding unit testing.

In my WPF application, on startup, I have something like :

```
 public App()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceA>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceB>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceC>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceD>();

        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Now for unit testing, Should I be creating a ServiceCollection, like in Test1? or should I be manually creating the dependencies like in Test2?

```
 public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMock<IServiceA>>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // test something ..
        var itemThatUsesServices = new(); // injected
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var serviceA = new Mock<IServiceA>();

        // test something ..
        var itemThatUsesServices = new(serviceA); // manual
    }
}
```

Is it bad practise to have a class like the following where instead of getting a dependency in the constructor, you get the dependency when it is needed? (imagine a case where the service is not available at the construction point). In which case, the unit test would HAVE to create a container?

```
 public class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public string Title { get; } = "The App";

    public MainViewModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger; // logger is injected

        // cannot inject IService in constructor as it doesn't exist yet.
    }

    public void UseService()
    {
        var service = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService>();

        // user service
    }
}
```

Comment: Test 1 is bad, Test 2 is good, because you want test your service class and not the DI container. Your example of ViewModel is bad, because it is the service locator pattern which is an anti-pattern.